# Is there a search feature in MavensMate?

Tags: mavensmate, search

I have started using Mavensmate along with Sublime last week and I am missing the search feature.

I am referring to the search for Apex code and not the "Find" feature which already exists? So I did a google search and reached [this page](https://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Shortcuts).

I haven't been able to locate any help on how to search for existing classes.
I am wondering if there is a feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Search all files for a substring

**Windows**

Sublime: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>

Eclipse: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>

**Mac**

Sublime: <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>

Eclipse: <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>

### Search for a file by name

**Windows**

Sublime: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>

Eclipse: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

**Mac**

Sublime: <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>

Eclipse: <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about searching for a class or page by name, then using

<kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> for Mac.

or

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> on Windows

will open a metadata search prompt where you can find project files very quickly. This is the only way I open files using Mavensmate and Atom.