# Way to see trigger using email template without going through CODE

Tags: apex, soql, workflow

If there is a way for me to easily see if any apex triggers are using email templates without looking through the code?

Comment: What does that even mean? You want to see the code body of the running `Apex Trigger`? You want to see the triggering record? Please [edit] your post to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: Wan to check if any trigger is using email template without going through the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a search feature in MavensMate?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102407/is-there-a-search-feature-in-mavensmate/102409#102409). Search options are outlined for both `Eclipse` and `Sublime`.

Comment: Going through your above update , We need to have a name. Isn't there a query as to check if email template is used and in which trigger /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I outline how to search files for a substring [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102407/is-there-a-search-feature-in-mavensmate/102409#102409).

The only way to use an `Email Template` in apex is by calling `SingleEmailMessage.setTemplateId` or `MassEmailMessage.setTemplateId`. So if you want to just look for anywhere templates are used, you can just do a global search for `setTemplateId(`.

If you want to search for use of a specific template name, it should be queried for by `DeveloperName`, though it might be queried for by `Name`, or it *could* even be merged in with a hard coded id */shakesfinger*. First search `'My_Developer_Name'`, then `'My_Name'`, then `'IdValue'`.