# How to search all Apex Classes in IntelliJ Illuminated Cloud?

Tags: ide, search, intellij

I am trying to search a code base for any reference to a particular `SObject` using IntelliJ IDEA (Illuminated Cloud). I tried using <kbd>Double Shift</kbd> as indicated within the interface, but when I search for references it returns nothing (even though I know there are some). This search seems to just be on the file name.

I found [this cheatsheet](https://www.zencloudtech.com/wp-content/uploads/intellijilluminatedcloud-shortcuts-zencloudtech1.pdf) which also seems to indicate <kbd>Double Shift</kbd> might be a good option, but I don't see anything else promising.

How can I search *within* all files for *a specific substring*. Similar to the first set of commands I posted here: [Is there a search feature in MavensMate?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/102409/2995) Is there a similar command on IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use "Find in Path", in the context menu shown by right clicking on the root of the project in the project navigation pane. This does a string search in the whole project structure.

If you want to use non-string searching, either open the SObject from the Offline Symbol Table (not the SObject's meta file) and use "Find Usages", or find an existing usage of the SObject in source code and use "Find Usages". Find usages is more sophisticated (you can find this in "Edit -> Find") and uses symbol searching rather than string searching.